# Why isn't it safe to run bitcoin core on a laptop?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet

I have read on some twitter posts that it was not safe to run bitcoin core on a laptop. That it was better to run it on a rasberry pie for example.

What are the main reasons this is not safe? How storing your btc on a laptop is more dangerous that storing them on a rasberry or another hardware (which most are not open source) ?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you link to where you read this? It may make sense with a bit more context.

Comment: Yes It was a debate around Coldcard: https://twitter.com/silentlink1/status/1455323246983852032?s=20.

Comment: I have no clue where that's coming from. You're probably better off debating this on twitter than here...

Comment: Ok nothing to worry then. There is no more risks running bitcoin core on a laptop with an unix distro that on a rasberry if I understand well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One main difference between a laptop and raspberry pi is that laptop will have several applications used regularly for different things so more likely to have some malware, whereas raspberry pi will be separate and only used for one thing 24/7 (running node). You can manage this with virtual machines or operating system like Qubes OS.

However considering basic things like backdoors in hardware, both have similar issues based on manufacturers.

Few alternatives for laptops and SBC(Single Board Computer) exist. Example: https://wiki.pine64.org/wiki/Main_Page#Devices

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. The argument about the applications running on the laptop is why people advise to "clean" it and to install a fresh OS. I was thinking about backdoors when I asked my question. Good to know it is a common issue for both solutions. I'll take a look at your link and learn more about it.